# Java file parser stuck in a recursive loop

Tags: java, parsing, recursion

I have a `Java` parser file that looks up files with a specific format:

> 20151202data.csv

The program is suppose to grab the current days file, parse it, and then return the data. However when today's file isn't available, I need it to roll back a day to yesterdays file. If yesterdays isn't there either i need it to die.

```
public static JSONArray getJSON(String dataLocation) {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    logger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode != 404){
        ...Parse...
    } else {
        errorCount++;

        if(errorCount > 1) {
            logger.info("Cannot find data.csv for" + getDayBefore(errorCount));
            return null;
        } else {
            logger.info("404: Today's file couldn't be found. Using " + getDayBefore(errorCount) + "data.csv");
            getJSON("/data/"+ getDayBefore(errorCount)+"data.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting stuck in a loop. Is there a better way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: where is the loop???

Comment: @StefanBeike when it doesn't find the file it continues to call `getJson` with yesterdays date even though its not there and even though the count should be > 1

Comment: You need a while loop, while (responseCode == 404) {//change the url and try again} and break from while loop as soon as you find the file.

Comment: @StefanBeike it is a recursive loop. `getJSON` calls itself.

Comment: @Raf what if it never finds a file

Comment: forget the while loop, since you already have recursive function. If it never finds the file then it means the file do not exist so there is nothing to parse, right? If you are worried about getJSON getting called even when the file do not exist then you need to see what is the value of errorCount because for some reason the if/else condition is not executing properly.

Comment: @Raf correct but i need it to rollback a day and then die. Rolling back a day isn't working I'm saying. There's no way to tell if it'll never find a file.

Answer (score -1):

Your logger call says getDayBefore(errorCount), but your getJSON call is using getDayBefore(count).  It looks like you should be using errorCount for both.